# I can't create tablespace in Oracle

Tags: linux, oracle

I have deployed an oracle database running on docker and use navicat to connect to the oracle database. But when I tried to created a tablespace, I failed to make it.

sql : `Create tablespace tbs datafile '/home/oracledb/tbs01.dbf' SIZE 2G autoextend ON NEXT 100M;`

The error stack :

ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file

Linux-x86_64 Error: 13: Permission denied

I'm not sure whether it is caused by the authority of the system user: oracle, or other reason. And if I just create the file use "touch", will it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the `oracledb` user (or whichever user is running the database) have permissions to create files on the `/home/oracledb` directory? If not, use `chmod` to give permissions (and/or add the oracle user to a group that does have permissions to write to that directory).

Comment: As far as the `touch` command, you could use it to _test_ whether the user invoking the command can create a file in that location (assuming it is the user `oracledb` as MT0 did), but no, you can't pre-create the file.